# Wasabi fails on build - Maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, ab-testing, intuit-wasabi

### See the solution below

---

*Using Ubuntu 16.04 on Google Cloud*

*Everything is done as noted here https://github.com/intuit/wasabi.*

---

After successfully bootstraping the wasabai
by running:

```
$ ./bin/wasabi.sh bootstrap
```

and getting

```
Everything looks all right!
...
installed dependencies.
```

Then I reboot the machine

```
$ sudo reboot
```

and try running the `build`

```
$ ./bin/wasabi.sh build
```

which obviously fails, this is the output I see:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 30 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 30 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] wasabi
[INFO] wasabi-experiment-objects
[INFO] wasabi-export
[INFO] wasabi-assignment-objects
[INFO] wasabi-exceptions
[INFO] wasabi-analytics-objects
[INFO] wasabi-authentication-objects
[INFO] wasabi-eventlog
[INFO] wasabi-auditlog-objects
[INFO] wasabi-authorization-objects
[INFO] wasabi-cassandra
[INFO] wasabi-database
[INFO] wasabi-feedback-objects
[INFO] wasabi-user-directory
[INFO] wasabi-repository
[INFO] wasabi-experiment
[INFO] wasabi-assignment
[INFO] wasabi-util
[INFO] wasabi-analytics
[INFO] wasabi-auditlog
[INFO] wasabi-event-objects
[INFO] wasabi-event
[INFO] wasabi-email
[INFO] wasabi-feedback
[INFO] wasabi-authentication
[INFO] wasabi-authorization
[INFO] wasabi-api
[INFO] wasabi-functional-test
[INFO] wasabi-main
[INFO] wasabi-swagger-ui
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building wasabi 1.0.20161107232436-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ wasabi ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (copy-resources) @ wasabi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/www/html/wasabi/wasabi/src/main/env
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:prepare-agent (prepare-agent) @ wasabi ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/silversillu/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.7.201606060606/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar=destfile=/var/www/html/wasabi/wasabi/target/jacoco.exec,excludes=com/intuit/wasabi/tests/**
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:report (post-unit-test) @ wasabi ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:report (report) @ wasabi ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (attach-javadocs) @ wasabi ---
[INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ wasabi ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:remove-project-artifact (remove-old-artifacts) @ wasabi ---
[INFO] /home/silversillu/.m2/repository/com/intuit/wasabi/wasabi removed.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.4:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ wasabi ---
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building wasabi-experiment-objects 1.0.20161107232436-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ wasabi-experiment-objects ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources (copy-resources) @ wasabi-experiment-objects ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/www/html/wasabi/wasabi/modules/experiment-objects/src/main/env
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:prepare-agent (prepare-agent) @ wasabi-experiment-objects ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/silversillu/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.7.201606060606/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar=destfile=/var/www/html/wasabi/wasabi/modules/experiment-objects/target/jacoco.exec,excludes=com/intuit/wasabi/tests/**
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ wasabi-experiment-objects ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/www/html/wasabi/wasabi/modules/experiment-objects/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ wasabi-experiment-objects ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 24 source files to /var/www/html/wasabi/wasabi/modules/experiment-objects/target/classes
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping wasabi
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] wasabi ............................................. SUCCESS [  4.085 s]
[INFO] wasabi-experiment-objects .......................... FAILURE [  0.633 s]
[INFO] wasabi-export ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-assignment-objects .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-exceptions .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-analytics-objects ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-authentication-objects ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-eventlog .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-auditlog-objects ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-authorization-objects ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-cassandra ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-database .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-feedback-objects ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-user-directory .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-repository .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-experiment .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-assignment .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-util ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-analytics ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-auditlog .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-event-objects ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-event ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-email ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-feedback .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-authentication .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-authorization ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-api ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-functional-test ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-main ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] wasabi-swagger-ui .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.399 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-10T21:48:24+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/70M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project wasabi-experiment-objects: Fatal error compiling: directory not found: /var/www/html/wasabi/wasabi/modules/experiment-objects/target/classes -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :wasabi-experiment-objects
error: invalid: mvn  -Pdevelopment clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true package javadoc:aggregate

usage: build.sh [options]

options:
  -b | --build [ true | false ]  : build; default: false
  -p | --profile [profile]       : build profile; default: development
  -t | --test [ true | false ]   : test; default: false
  -h | --help                    : help message
```

---

### Solution

I don't know if it makes any sense but what fixed the issue was moving my cloud machine from **micro** to much more powerful one **n1-standard-4 (4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory)**

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following:

```
% WASABI_MAVEN="-e -X" ./bin/wasabi.sh build
```

additionally one could try issuing the reported failed mvn invocation directly, ie:

```
% mvn -e -X -Pdevelopment clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true package javadoc:aggregate
```

clearly none of the codebase is compiling given the first module fails.

i don't see why a reboot would matter unless logged in as a different user, some directory is owned by 'root' and not writable/deletable, etc.

let's fix this :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. IDK if it makes any sense but what fixed the issue was moving my cloud machine from **micro** to much more powerful one **n1-standard-4 (4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory)**

Comment: thx for giving #wasabi a go :) i suspect there was a file permission issue, or filled up partition, etc. you are writing to root iirc /var/www/...

Comment: Could be, really looking forward to running some real experiments on it :)

Comment: hey @james-todd, before I ask a new question, do you know how to serve the Wasabi API over HTTPS?

Comment: hey @SilverRingvee ... man i so failed to follow up here. my bad :( we should consider picking up this conversation in wasabi/gitter [ https://gitter.im/intuit/wasabi ] ... but in short, wasabi uses autumn [ https://github.com/intuit/Autumn ] which is basically jetty/jersey/jackson/guice/et-al wrapped up. autumn includes an https endpoint [ https://github.com/intuit/Autumn/blob/develop/modules/web/src/main/java/com/intuit/autumn/web/HttpsService.java ] so all that remains is binding in the https certs, config, restart :) appologies agian on the delay in getting back on this one :(